# I want to read the lines that ends with ‘edu’ but in vain

Tags: python, python-3.x

Kindly help me in below mentioned code

```
with open('k.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        if line.endswith('edu'):   
            print(line)
```

Comment: Most lines end with a newline character.  Try stripping the lines of whitespace first:  `if line.strip().endswith('edu'):`

Comment: Thanks a lot its working

Comment: This is a fairly common problem, but I can't find a dupe... anyone?